# Invalid Scope Type 'default' magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, console

I used the command bin/magento setup:upgrade and it returned

> Invalid Scope type 'default'

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

it's because of your core_config_data table
check the scope columns

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a line break before the string, instead of

```
'
default'
```

it should be

```
'default'
```

This can be either on *core_config_data* table in the database, or in *app/etc/env.php* file